# Powershell script to zip folder base on their name with the command compress-archive

Tags: powershell, zip, basename, compress-archive

I'm trying to compress each folder in my directory into a zip with the same name

I tried the simple compress-archive command

```
Compress-Archive $targetFolderPath -Destination $zipFolder -Update
```

but it gives me only one zip named ".zip" with all my folder in it, that's not what I want

Then I've found this, which is my best attempt :

```
Get-ChildItem $targetFolderPath -Directory | foreach { compress-archive $_ $_.basename -update}
```

I find one folder for one zip with the correct name which is good, however I cannot choose the destination directory

Can anybody see what I need to do to make this run ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. You can still transform it to a one-liner, if so desired, but I prefer a little more verbosity as the code is easier to read.

```
$Folders = @(Get-ChildItem $TargetFolderPath -Directory)

foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {

    $Zipfile = Join-Path -Path $ZipFolder -ChildPath ($Folder.name + '.zip')

    try {
        Compress-Archive `
            -Path $Folder.FullName `
            -DestinationPath $Zipfile `
            -CompressionLevel Fastest `
            -Update `
            -ErrorAction Stop
    } catch {
        Write-Warning "Unable to archive $($Folder.FullName): $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought that a command like Join-Path could help me. One more question,"@" you mentionned on $Folders variable is necessary ?

Comment: The `@` is to make sure that Powershell always returns a collection, even if there is just a single object.